# Computer ran out of battery while formatting an MicroSD card, now card is not recognized

Tags: sd-card

I bought a new Samsung 256GB Pro Endurance Micro SD Card.  I wanted to format it so I could load an operating system for a Raspberry Pi. My laptop running Ubuntu 23.04 died for lack of power in the middle of the formatting operation. I didn't have it plugged in. Now the card, which formerly was recognized as /dev/sdb is not recognized by the system although I remove and reinsert it.

Has the power off FUBARred the card or is there a way to save it?

Comment: From the point of view of the card, formatting it is not that special. So, chances are it's alright, but I'm worried by the fact you say it's not recognized. So, running `lsblk` doesn't list it?

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: @Marcus Muller lsblk lists it.  sdb      8:16   1 238.8G  0 disk 
df does not.

Comment: @SteveCohen two different things alltogether: `df` only shows *mounted filesystem*. Your SD card contains no (workable) filesystem, and isn't mounted. `lsblk` cares about block devices, and your SD card is there. So just format it again.

Comment: @sudodus thanks.  Back in business!  Thanks. Marcus Muller -thanks